# Setting up compiler in Qt 5.0.1 MSVC2010

Tags: qt, compiler-construction

I just installed Qt 5.0.1 MSVC2010 32bit, i need to configure the Kits and the compiler. I have installed minGW and its detected by Qt Automatically. But at Qt Version tab in Tools->Option->Build & Run menu, i get this:

> No compiler can produce code for this Qt version

What should I do? which compiler I have to use? I can't build/run anything.

Comment: For compiling with MinGW you need MinGW edition of Qt 5. MSVC2010 is only compilable with MS Visual Studio 2010.

Comment: i have to install MS Visual Studio 2010?. thanks anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should either use MSVS 2010 for your downloaded Qt or download the [MinGW Qt distribution](http://releases.qt-project.org/qt5/5.0.1/qt-windows-opensource-5.0.1-mingw47_32-x86-offline.exe).